# WP7 IsolatedFileStorageStream - Wrong Byte size

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, byte, isolatedstoragefile

Using c#, I am downloading a file from a url the user enters on the phone. When it is writing the file to the IsolatedStorage, it is writing too many bytes to the file and therefore, the program used to open these files will not open.

When I debug, the bit size is 451,258 bytes, but when the file is exported from IsolatedStorage it is 454,656 bytes.  It is filling the remaining space with spaces.  Is there anyway to adjust this file size? Trim off the extra space at the end and save?

Forgive my ignorance as I am new at C# and WP7 developoment. I would really appreciate the help.

Here is my code :

```
       public void readCompleteCallback(Object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            try
            {
                //string fileName = txtUrl.Text.Substring(txtUrl.Text.LastIndexOf("/") + 1).Trim();
                string fileName = "DownloadedNZB.nzb";
                bool isSpaceAvailable = IsSpaceIsAvailable(e.Result.Length);

                if (isSpaceAvailable)
                {
                    // Save mp3 to Isolated Storage
                    using (var isfs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName,
                                        FileMode.CreateNew,
                                        IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()))
                    {
                        long fileLen = e.Result.Length;
                        byte[] b = new byte[fileLen];
                        e.Result.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
                        isfs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
                        isfs.Flush();
                        isfs.Close();
                        MessageBox.Show("File downloaded successfully");                      
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Not enough to save space available to download the file");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I bet you mean file size instead of bit size. All bits are equally sized as far as I know.... and that goes for byte size too...

Comment: it seems to be filling it out to the next Block size...just really need a way of trimming the end of the file - think that would fix it. But i dont know. Thanks

Comment: The bug is in the Read() call, you ignore its return value.  You have to loop to read all the bytes until Read() returns 0.

Comment: Hans,Thanks very much for the reply, is it in this code that needs to be changed :

                            long fileLen = e.Result.Length;
                            byte[] b = new byte[fileLen];
                            e.Result.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
                            isfs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
                            isfs.Flush();
                            isfs.Close();
Could you give me an example of how to look through the bytes? New to C# :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
e.Result.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
isfs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
isfs.Flush();
isfs.Close();
```

with

```
var numberOfBytesRead = e.Result.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
isfs.Write(b, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
isfs.Flush();
isfs.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks Emo for the suggestion, the bytes still look correct when I debug the code, however when the file is saved, I still have a line and a half of spaces (" ") after the closing </xml> tag. Therefore, the xml opening/processing applciation cannot open it.
  
Is there any way of trimming the extra spaces after the closing </xml> tag?

Comment: Did the change I suggested change the size of the file?

Comment: Thanks fir your reply. It didn't change the original size of the file. :(

Comment: Could you provide a download/url of the file, so I could have a look?

Comment: This problem seems to be alright now...I did a rebuild of the code and it is now working.